# If I install more RAM should I boot into 64bit Kernel? Does it matter?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, performance, 64-bit, adobe-lightroom

I've got an Early-2009 Unibody Mac Book Pro 17".

It came with 4 GB RAM and by default it boots into 32-bit Kernel.

I've just upgraded to 8 GB RAM and my main concern is getting maximum performance from my 64-bit version of Lightroom 3 (I scan negatives and edit large tiff files).

Now that I've got 8 GB RAM, will booting into 64-bit Kernel give me any performance boost on Lightroom (and even generally)?

Should I see a performance boost on 32-bit Kernel with the additional RAM?

Comment: Adding RAM should give you performance improvements unless you had a lot to begin with. It might be a little faster to use the 64 bit kernel, but it probably won't make much difference compared to doubling the RAM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this article at macperformanceguide.com](http://macperformanceguide.com/SnowLeopard-64bit.html), you will see performance gains (5-30%) by running graphics applications in 64-bit mode.

Note that you don't necessarily need to switch to a 64-bit Kernel, you just need to [ensure that Lightroom runs in 64-bit mode](http://macperformanceguide.com/SnowLeopard-64bit.html#OpenIn64Bit).

Comment: According to [this other article at macperformanceguide.com](http://macperformanceguide.com/SnowLeopard-Performance.html), you'll get an additional (generally small) performance boost from running under a 64-bit kernel as well.  In that article, he saw a 3% speed increase importing files into Lightroom 2.4 (that's in addition to the 27% speed increase from running Lightroom itself in 64-bit mode).

Answer (score 2):

As per Apple's web site, no.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4287